# If $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz, then $g(x)=f(x,a)$ too?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continous function, meaning that

$ |f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_2,y_2)| \leq L \, || (x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2) ||$

for all $(x_i,y_i) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $|| \cdot ||$ is the euclidean norm.

For a constant $a \in \mathbb{R}$, is $g(x) := f(x,a), g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, also Lipschitz continous (with the same Lipschitz constant $L$)?

(This is not homework, I'm just wondering. I assume the answer is Yes, but I can't proof it)

**The previous formulation of this problem contained an error ($f$ was not real-valued). I'm sorry if I caused any confusion.**

Comment: Please write what it means that $f$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: I added the definition. I meant Lipschitz continous as a mapping between two metric spaces.

Comment: Ok so now you don't see two point $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ that could give you what you want. If not, write what it means that $g$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: $f(\cdot, a)$ is $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$. How come you have $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Oh... I meant $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Now that was stupid :) Thanks for pointing that out, the previous formulation of my problemwas incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|g(x_1)-g(x_2)|=|f(x_1,a)-f(x_2,a)|\leq L\,\|(x_1,a)-(x_2,a)\|=L\,\|(x_1-x_2,0)\|=L\,|x_1-x_2|.$$

Comment: That was easy, thank you!

Comment: @user3926 I know, right? You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** norms on a finite dimentionnal space are equivalent:
$\exists C>0\,\,\,\, \|(x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2)\|\le C (|x_1-x_2| + |y_1-y_2|)$